# SSRS dataset query not ordering by properly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have a dataset text query and I would like to have an ORDER BY in it. The issue is in SSRS, the ORDER BY is not working as desired. However, when I run the query in SSMS, the output is ordered as I would like.

This image is in SSMS where it is working properly. The payroll = 000004 is just to isolate a specific payroll to make it easier to read. The ISNULL(OrderByNumber, 1000) is just to put the total row down at the bottom.

[image]

Here is a picture of dataset query where the ORDER BY resides

[image]

And here is the results I get in SSRS preview. Not ordered how I want at all :( As far as I can tell, SSRS should support ORDER BY in the dataset query. I also tried removing the ISNULL( ,1000), and the order by still didn't function as desired.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any grouping on the tablix?  How about removing the order by from the SQL Server and applying it to the tablix itself?

Comment: Hmph. I feel like I tried that before, but I just tried again. Going to the Row Group Details and putting a sorting of (=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!OrderByNumber.Value), 100, Fields!OrderByNumber.Value)) does the trick. Thanks for reminding me I can do that with SSRS instead of everything from SQL :)

Comment: I would still like to get an answer that allows me to do this in SQL

Comment: Any reason why?  I spend a lot of time changing queries to do sorts outside of SQL server, ie in the application layer. Sorting can be an expensive operation and require temp db etc. Typically resource is going to cost less in the app than the SQL server. A bit different when you are talking about SSRS as it's licensed as a component of SQL server. Same principle applies though, I don't see any SSRS instances running at capacity

Comment: @SimonHellings I suppose just for my piece of mind. It doesn't make sense to me to have a query that works when ran in SSMS, but not in the SSRS dataset query.